# Why does Amenadiel think he is no longer worthy to have his powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

In **season 2**, **episode 5** - **"The Weaponizer"**, Amenadiel faces Uriel and it doesn't  have a sweet end. When Lucifer comes back, happy, to hear the brother's story is surprised. Amenadiel is wasted, and confess that he **no longer has his powers**.

And that's **the first part I'm confused about**, Amenadiel questions that he is no longer worthy of his power.

[image: Amenadiel questions his worthy]

After that, **the second part that I'm confused about too**, Lucifer says that it was the best thing that ever happened.

[image: Lucifer answering]

So after all my explanation, why does Amenadiel think he's no longer worthy to have his powers, and why does Lucifer say that to his closest brother at the moment? It doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: Can someone say me, if there is another TV Show similar to this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [theses subtitles](https://subscene.com/subtitles/lucifer-second-season-2016/english/1432141):

> I no longer have my powers.
>
> Well, what happened to them?
>
> Oh, I don't know, Luci, pick a sin. Is it because I released a damned
>   soul from Hell? Slept with a demon? Is it because I'm working with
>   you? Or because of Mom? Or am I simply no longer worthy? (sniffles)
>   It's time that I faced the truth, brother. I've fallen.
>
> Well. Welcome to the club. Meetings are on Tuesdays.
>
> It's different for me, Luci. It's different. I no longer have my
>   powers. My very strength...
>
> Big deal! It's probably the best thing that ever happened to you.

We don't really know why, but there could be various reasons as he stated : demon affair, helping Mom, helping Lucifer, Mom interference, etc.
In this episode, they said also that no-one really knows what want God, and what he does really, and why is someone worthy or not.

For the point of Lucifer, Amenadiel was always very powerful (that was his "gift", while Uriel's one was "prediction", Lucifer knows desires, etc., he simply was more powerful), so he now understands what's being over-powered, defenseless.
Also, he's fallen, as Lucifer whom was casted away from Heaven and had to rules over Hells. He's no longer help by God, he's alone, like Lucifer. But also, he doesn't really care, he said "Big Deal", Lucifer already faced that from a long time, and he has urgent matter (saving Chloe from Uriel).